# How to write generic xpath?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to write generic XPath for the below sites. Both sites have same elements on UI, but DOM structure is different while interacting with elements.

Here I am trying to get the text of left eye and right eye quantity

I am getting a text when I am using below XPath for Norway and UK respectively but when I am trying to write generic XPath which will work on both sites I am facing an issue :

So I wrote below XPath will work on both sites but it's not.

```
//a[contains(@id,'qty-1')]
```

**Expected Behaviour:**

I want Quantity for both left and right eye element on both sites with the same XPATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Norway there's subscribe and for UK payment blocks. For Norway there're two HTML div `.one-off` and `.subscribe` under `.payment-option.row.two-eyes` css selectors. For UK only `.one-off`.

If you want generic xpath for both, use below:

Left: `//div[contains(@class,'payment-option')]//div[contains(@class,'-selected') and (@style='display: block;' or @style='')]//div[contains(@class,'-left-eye')]//span[@class='ui-selectmenu-status']`

Right: `//div[contains(@class,'payment-option')]//div[contains(@class,'-selected') and (@style='display: block;' or @style='')]//div[contains(@class,'-right-eye')]//span[@class='ui-selectmenu-status']`

This xpath is depends on the position in the document and not "safe". My suggestion is to use separate with simple locators or use `div[class$='-right-eye'] .ui-selectmenu-status` css selector, find all elements and filter by visibility.

Comment: When I am trying to select oneoff from Norway then again above XPath is not working even I already tried css selector, which you mentioned above

Comment: Your question was about how to write xpath and get text, not how to select. And I gave you correct answer. If you need to select and do not know how, ask another question

Comment: Yes, I have get text of norway and uk region for both oneoff and subscription , but fail to do that. Can you please help?

Comment: If the answer works accept it is correct way. For another case you always can ask new question

Comment: no actually its not working thats the reason I am asking here sorry about that

Comment: Again, you ask how to write generic xpath and get text. And it's works. Select value is completely different question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200868/discussion-between-sers-and-rock).

Comment: Yes mate I want to get tet of quantity (both left and right eye) for a Norway region (one-off and subscription) & for UK I have only oneoff so would you be kind enough to help me